# Turn object with (possible nested) arrays into an array of objects with single-item arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that can turn this array:

```
const originalObj = {
    field: "parent",
    msg:[{
        field: "child1a",
        msg: [{
            field: "child2a",
            msg: "child2a-msg"
        },
        {
            field: "child2b",
            msg: "child2b-msg"
        }
      ]
    }, {
        field: "child1b",
        msg: "child1b-msg"
    }
  ]
};
```

Into this one:

```
[
    {
    field: "parent",
    msg: [
      {
        field: "child1a",
        msg: [
          {
            field: "child2a",
            msg: "child2a-msg"
          }
        ]  
      },
    ]
    },
  {
    field: "parent",
    msg: [
      {
        field: "child1a",
        msg: [
          {
            field: "child2b",
            msg: "child2b-msg"
          }
        ]  
      },
    ]
    },
  {
    field: "parent",
    msg: [
        {
        field: "child1b",
        msg: "child1b-msg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So, to be clear: the msg object can be either a string or a single item array.

It should be recursive; since a msg-object can contain an array, which can contain a deeper msg-object, which can contain another array, etc.

Here is my attempt, but I can't figure it out. 
https://jsfiddle.net/rnacken/42e7p8hz/31/

As you can see in the fiddle, the arrays are nested, parent is missing and I'm missing a child. I am afraid I am way lost and on the wrong track here.

Comment: why do you want it as an array of single object?
It would be more convenient, if you keep it as an Object, which is actual purpose of `flatten`?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan Good question. That would certainly be more convenient, but the project also deals with async stuff that may add another (nested) message to an existing object. The question was meant to create an easy parsable logging function.

Comment: alright, I have added the answer.. You can use my function, it is done with recursion, also upvote any comment that you find helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate `msg` and build a new nested part result of the nested items. Then iterate and build single objects for the result array.

```js
function getSingle({ field, msg }) {
    var array = [];

    if (!msg || !Array.isArray(msg)) {
        return [{ field, msg }];
    }
    msg.forEach(o => getSingle(o).forEach(s => array.push({ field, msg: [s] })));
    return array;
}

var object = { field: "parent", msg: [{ field: "child1a", msg: [{ field: "child2a", msg: [{ field: "child3a", msg: "child3a-msg" }, { field: "child3b", msg: "child3b-msg" }] }, { field: "child2b", msg: "child2b-msg" }] }, { field: "child1b", msg: "child1b-msg" }] };

console.log(getSingle(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Pure poetry Nina! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I have added a simple recursive approach that you can use.

```
const originalObj = {
    field: "parent",
    msg: [
    {
        field: "child1a",
        msg: [
        {
            field: "child2a",
            msg: "child2a-msg"
        },
        {
            field: "child2b",
            msg: "child2b-msg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      field: "child1b",
      msg: "child1b-msg"
    }
  ]
};

const flatten = ({field, msg}) =>  {
    const res = []; // creating an array to create the msg array in case of multiple entries in msg
    if (typeof msg === "string") {
        return {field, msg}; // return plain object if the msg is "string"
    }
    if (msg.constructor === Array) {
        // recursion here
        msg.map(message => flatten(message, msg))
        .forEach(m => {
            // after flattening array msg, we push them to msg field
            res.push({field, msg: m})
        });
    }
    return res; // returning final result here
}
const newObj = flatten(originalObj);
```

With `flatten` function you can map any depth of array and expect the same result.